# Mysqli statement execute not working in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a prepare() function, which is not working. (In case it wasn't clear in the title.)

I put my mysqli connection into a $GLOBAL entry, since I did not want declare it everywhere. There were problems, where I couldn't use it inside classes, if it wasn't declared inside them.

```
include_once '../lib/init.php';
ob_start();
    var_dump($GLOBALS['mysqli']);
    print '<br />';
    print $GLOBALS['mysqli']->server_info;
    print '<br />';
```

I use these at the start of the page, and they do return connections that seem to work. (??)

```
object(mysqli)#1 (19) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(0) ["client_info"]=> string(79) "mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 3c688b6bbc30d36af3ac34fdd4b7b5b787fe5555 $" ["client_version"]=> int(50011) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["field_count"]=> int(0) ["host_info"]=> string(25) "Localhost via UNIX socket" ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["server_info"]=> string(6) "5.6.29" ["server_version"]=> int(50629) ["stat"]=> string(153) "Uptime: 7820870 Threads: 1 Questions: 484247043 Slow queries: 14126 Opens: 837433 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 2000 Queries per second avg: 61.917" ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["protocol_version"]=> int(10) ["thread_id"]=> int(76093624) ["warning_count"]=> int(0) }
5.6.29
```

As you can see, the object is returned, and responding to properties and method calls. However, when I try to prepare a statement:

```
$stmt = $GLOBALS['mysqli']->prepare("SELECT 
                                    ".$GLOBALS['user_tbl']."_id 
                                FROM 
                                    ".$GLOBALS['user_tbl']." 
                                WHERE 
                                        ".$GLOBALS['user_tbl']."_name = ? 
                                    AND 
                                        ".$GLOBALS['user_tbl']."_password = ?");
    print $stmt->error;
    var_dump($stmt);
```

Seemingly it does return a statement, and even better, without error. However, it does nothing, beside returning no errors:

```
object(mysqli_stmt)#2 (10) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(0) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(2) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["id"]=> int(1) } object(mysqli_stmt)#2 (10) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(0) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(2) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["id"]=> int(1) }
```

And this very same line is returned when I use:

```
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['name'], password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
    var_dump($stmt);
    $stmt->execute();
    var_dump($stmt);
```

yet the statement is still empty, and unable to retrieve any results from it. I have checked the $GLOBALS array, it does contain every necessary variables I'm trying to use, but still no avail. :(

Empty result:

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
    var_dump($result);
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    var_dump($row);
    print '<br />userid'.$row[$GLOBALS['user_tbl'].'_id'].'<br />';
```

This is how I declared my connection in the init.php, in case it's needed:

```
$GLOBALS['mysqli'] = new mysqli("localhost", "name", "password", "databasename");
// check connection
if ($GLOBALS['mysqli']->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $GLOBALS['mysqli']->connect_error);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: you never execute your prepared statement $stmt->execute();

Comment: The second code, you execute, but you never fetch your results. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Comment: Sigh, because it's empty, no reason to fetch anything...

Comment: Don't trust num_rows: `Returns the number of rows in the result set. The use of mysqli_stmt_num_rows() depends on whether or not you used mysqli_stmt_store_result() to buffer the entire result set in the statement handle.`  Try to fetch it anyway.

Comment: I just cut the code into smaller pieces for easier reading, there is a fetch in it, out it into the question, but it's empty.

Comment: If it still isn't returning anything, echo your query, and then try passing it directly into your database with the values replaced.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name = 'admin' AND user_password = '$2y$10$8T5Uf6R8O8dFKRI1KeMBKu3AA2LFlqmdOtLQgHl.UyuqKwLsX8MFy'` The query does actually work directly in the database, but it doesn't even work if I use $mysqli->query($query); I guess it could be something with the connection? But it doesn't give any errors. :(

Comment: temporary remove 2nd argument from your query, or just remove `WHERE` completely to check if you can get all records from DB

Comment: I do get it from the DB directly, but not through the prepare statement, or the query.

Comment: simplify - start with `var_dump($GLOBALS['mysqli']->query("SELECT * FROM ".$GLOBALS['user_tbl'])->fetch_assoc());` - this will return an array or `null`

Answer (score 0):

AllenJB: Acutally changing to password_verify() not only better, but fixed the empty bind_param and execute problems.

```
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['name'], password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
```

Using password_hash here somehow doesn't work. I don't bind the posted password anymore, and verifying instead at PHP server side, and now I got the correct results from the database.

(Thanks for Sjon too for walking through me the debug process too.)